# Getting NaN when calculating difference of two dates using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following code. I'm trying to calculate date difference but it's output is NaN. Any idea where I am wrong ?

```
    var start = "01/01/2018"; //dd/mm/yyyy format
    var end = "09/01/2018"
    var date1 = new Date(start);
    var date2 = new Date(end);

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(parseInt((date2 - date1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)));

    alert(diffDays);
```

Comment: Which browser are you running this in?

Comment: Chrome browser.

Comment: works perfectly on Chrome.

Comment: Moreover, the format when you build `Date` from string is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: can you show what you are getting for `console.log( date1, date2)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you were getting NaN - I suspect you're running subtly different code to what you showed here, but you should be aware that the browswer is interpreting `09/01/2018` as the 1st September, not the 9th January as you expect - and as a result of using `Math.abs` you're actually getting a value of 242, where I suspect you're expecting 8.

The solution is to use a non-ambiguous format for specifying dates, which is `yyyy-mm-dd`. This is evaluated correctly in all cases.

The following code works (and gives the expected answer) on Chrome, FF & IE/Edge

```js
var start = "2018-01-01"; // yyyy-mm-dd format
var end = "2018-01-09"
var date1 = new Date(start);
var date2 = new Date(end);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(parseInt((date2 - date1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)));

console.log(diffDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved by below code. Hope It will help others too.Thanks for everyone

```
var start = "01/01/2018";


var startD = new Date(start);
var end = "09/01/2018";
var endD = new Date(end);


var report_date_string = new String(start);
var rectify_date_string = new String(end);

var report_date_final = report_date_string.split('/');
var month1 = report_date_final[0];
var day1 = report_date_final[1];
var year1 = report_date_final[2];

var rectify_date_final = rectify_date_string.split('/');
var month2 = rectify_date_final[0];
var day2 = rectify_date_final[1];
var year2 = rectify_date_final[2];

var report_datetime = new Date(year1,  day1,month1 - 1);


var rectify_datetime = new Date(year2, day2,month2 - 1);


var diff = Math.abs(((rectify_datetime.getTime() - report_datetime.getTime()) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)));

alert(diff);
```